# bunifu material textbox mode password is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to create a login page based C# desktop application. I use the bunifu toolbox to create a login page design. But when I want to create a password field using the bunifumaterialtextbox, the textbox does not show any changes / it only displays alphabet. It looks like the ispassword contained in the textbox properties is not working. So what should I do so that this texbox can display the correct password (not displaying alphabeth) when the program is run ?. I apologize for any errors in this question.

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit by providing us more details (like screen or code ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new using the **Bunifu framework** tool and I had the same problem then you. The solution I found was to invoke the **_TextBox** method which I suppose that gives you all the normal **TextBox** controls.

My code was something like this:
**txtPassword._TextBox.PasswordChar = '*';**

I loaded this code inside the **Form_Load** code block. It worked for me, hope that be useful for you too. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

is just a easy solution i have found

```
private void passbox_OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    passbox.isPassword = true;
}
```

Comment: it work sound great, but how it working. May be it just have to set once

Answer (score 0):

in side the properties tab of the bunifu text box there is a property **ispassword** set it to **true**.
to fully make the bunifu textbox to passwordbox you have to do the following:

- 1.in side the properties tab of the bunifu text box there is a property **ispassword** set it to **False**.
- 2.create an event of Enter and use the following code:
- 3.create an event of Leave and use the following code:

  ```
  private void txtpassword_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (txtpassword.Text == "Password")
      {
          txtpassword.Text = "";
          txtpassword.isPassword = true;
      }
  }

  private void txtpassword_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (txtpassword.Text == "")
      {
          txtpassword.Text = "Password";
          txtpassword.isPassword = false;
      }
  }
  ```

  4. like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UseSystemPasswordChar` property in your text box.

Example:

```
TextBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem's solution is  using enter,leave and textchange event such as below code if the name of your text box is txtPassword:

```
 private void txtPassword_TextChange(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      
        if (txtPassword.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            txtPassword.PasswordChar = '*';
        }
        else
        {
            txtPassword.PasswordChar = '\0';
        }


    }

    private void txtPassword_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtPassword.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            txtPassword.PasswordChar = '\0';
            
            txtPassword.TextPlaceholder = "insert your placeholder..";



        }
     
    }

    private void txtPassword_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUserName.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            txtPassword.PasswordChar = '*';
            txtPassword.PlaceholderText = "";
        }


    }
```